# What's happening when declaring array with a few empy elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If you saw that code, you know about result:

```
var a = [,1,2];
var b = [1,2,];
alert(a.length + b.length);
```

That's **5**.

But what about next code:

```
var a = [,1,2];
var b = [1,2,,,];
alert(a.length + b.length);
```

The result is **7**.

I'd like to know, is there an explanation and what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A leading comma creates an empty element. Trailing commas do also, except that a *final* trailing comma does not.

You can experiment with this is your console very easily.

Comment: note - If I remember correctly, I think some of the old IE versions didn't allow trailing commas.

Comment: Well, it seems like a silly thing to do anyway. In javascript, there's no need to allocate memory blocks ahead of time.

Comment: As a second note: The value of those elements is `undefined`, so it's 'empty' but not in the sense of an empty string, like `""` for example.